# Why is react useState not updating the values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, use-state

I am using an API to fetch data, but in order to fetch all the data I am required to loop through the links

```
 const [characterData, setCharacterData] = useState([]);
 const [link, setLink] = useState("https://swapi.dev/api/people/");

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    async function getData() {
        while (link) {
            const fetchedData = await fetch(link);
            const jsonData = await fetchedData.json();
            setCharacterData([...characterData, jsonData.results]);
            setLink(jsonData.next);
            console.log(link)
        }
        
    }
```

This is how one of the jsonData from above would look like:

{
"next": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",  "previous": null,  "results": [list of the wanted data] }

The last object will have "next": null, so the while loop should end at some point, but for some reason setLink() never updates the link and causes it to become an infinite loop. Link always remains as "https://swapi.dev/api/people/".

Another problem is that the page isn't displaying anything as characterData gets updated, so I am assuming that characterData isn't updating either, but I am not sure.

```
characterData.map((character, index) => {
      return (
           <div className="character-item" key={index}>
               <h4>{character.name}</h4>
               <p>{character.birth_year}</p>
           </div>
      );
})
```

Note: Each character is an object

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` is declared with `const` - it'll never change in a given render. So the

```
while (link) {
```

will run forever.

Unless you're using the `link` elsewhere, I'd remove it from state entirely and use a local variable inside `getData` instead. Make sure to use the callback form of `setCharacterData` too so that you don't lose the prior value in state.

```
async function getData() {
    let link = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/';
    while (link) {
        const fetchedData = await fetch(link);
        const jsonData = await fetchedData.json();
        setCharacterData(characterData => [...characterData, jsonData.results]);
        link = jsonData.next;
    }
}
```

It would also be a great idea to catch possible errors:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData()
        .catch(handleErrors);
}, [])
```